# binary tree insertion using recursion (clarification)

Tags: java, binary-tree

I have the following code to insert into the binary tree:

```
public void insert(T item) {
    root = insert(item, root);
}


private Node insert(T item, Node node) {
    if(node == null){
        return new Node(item, null, null);

    } else {

        if(item.compareTo(node.item) > 0) {
            node.rightChild = insert(item, node.rightChild);
        } else {
            node.leftChild = insert(item, node.leftChild);
        }
    }        

    return node;
}
```

the code works fine, I have tested it

my question is, how come the root is never changed since in the public function I assigned the returned node from the private function to the root

Thank you!

Comment: Please edit your title. We know you need help, you wouldn’t be here otherwise. Summarize the problem instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The public insert is just an interface into the recursive method which rebuilds the tree as the stack unwinds ending where you started, at the root (`root = ...`). Except for the first insert, you go left or right until you insert at the leaf level. Without any balancing, you will have the same root (assuming no removals) for the lifetime of the tree. Therefore, the only time the root changes on insert is when it's empty.

*Note: There's also a matter of what happens when a node is inserted with an existing value; do you discard it, allow duplicates, or swap the objects? That's an implementation detail.*

Comment: got it! thank you so much! .. to answer your question, I call find function before calling the insert and if it returns true then I discard the value with a warning message to the user .. thanks again

Comment: No problem. That sounds reasonable enough. Good luck @Someone!

Answer (score 1):

I read your code again and your code is correct. The return value is always the root element because your frist function call is `insert(item, root)` and the return value is what you give.